# How can I avoid duplicated code in this situation?

Tags: c#, oop

I built a javascript script that creates dynamic forms, and I'm creating a validation for each section that the user creates, that updates the title from the duplicated questions. So, I built a method for that. The user can choose between creating a section with dropboxes, checkboxes...

So, I had to create 6 methods with exacly the same code, I'm only changing the type of the list. Is there any wait to prevent that, creating a generic method?

```
    private static int CheckDuplicatedDropdownQuestions(Template template, int i, List<string> collectQuestions)
    {
        foreach (var field in template.Fields.Dropdown)
        {
            if (!collectQuestions.Contains(field.Title))
            {
                collectQuestions.Add(field.Title);
            }
            else
            {
                field.Title = field.Title + " (" + i + ")";
                i++;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say _I'm only changing the type of the list_ ? The list you are passing in? How are you changing it? Can you add one of the duplicated methods so we can see more clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you could add an example of another duplicate function, so we can see them side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new method for the foreach part

```
     private static int CheckDuplicatedDropdownQuestions(Template template, int i, 
    List<string> collectQuestions,string field)
    {
        if(field=="Dropdown")
        {
           NewMethod(template.Fields.Dropdown,ref i);
        }
        else if(field=="CheckBox")
        {
           NewMethod(template.Fields.CheckBox,ref i);
        }

        return i;
    }

    private static void NewMethod(var FieldType,ref int i)
    {
        foreach (var field in FieldType)
        {
            if (!collectQuestions.Contains(field.Title))
            {
                collectQuestions.Add(field.Title);
            }
            else
            {
                field.Title = field.Title + " (" + i + ")";
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't compiled it. Idea was to share the logic.